# How do you connect Simscape elements to other elements in the MATLAB/Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

I have problem connecting different elements from Simscape to other elements in the Simulink file.

I saw other postings on this issue and tried the connectors shown below but didn't work. The same elements do not exist in the Simscape so I am not really sure how to proceed.

To see the Simulink picture, visit: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/463199-how-do-you-connect-simscape-elements-to-other-elements-in-the-simulink

I appreciate any feedback. I use MATLAB R2018b.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Simscape blocks can have two different types of ports: a [physical connection port](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/connectionport.html) and a [physical signal port](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ug/basic-principles-of-modeling-physical-networks.html#bq89sba-8), and there are strict rules about what port can be connected to what port.

The physical connection ports can only be connected to other physical connection ports of the same domain (i.e. an electrical port can only be connected to another electrical port, but not a mechanical or hydraulic one, etc...) and therefore not to Simulink signals.

Likewise, the physical signal ports can only be connected to other physical ports, i.e. from a physical signal output port to a physical signal input port, and again not to Simulink signals.

Now, to interface Simulink blocks to Simscape blocks, there are the [Simulink-PS Converter](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/simulinkpsconverter.html) and the [PS-Simulink Converter](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/pssimulinkconverter.html) blocks, which convert Simulink (resp. physical) signals into physical (resp. Simulink) signals, and these are what you should be using to interface your Simscape model with the rest of your Simulink model.

I suggest you have a look at [Connecting Simscape Diagrams to Simulink Sources and Scopes](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ug/connecting-simscape-diagrams-to-simulink-sources-and-scopes.html) in the documentation for examples of how to do that.