# How to connect elements form different simscape sub-libraries?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape, simulink-library

Specifically, my group is working on thermal modeling of EVs i.e cabin cooling and battery cooling. We have used most elements from the two-phase-fluid sub-library of simscape. But at two connections we want a controlled separation of the refrigerant flow. For that, there is an element called flow divider but it's in the hydraulics sub-library. So how do I use these libraries simultaneously? I'm trying since yesterday but nothings seem to work. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you connect Simscape elements to other elements in the MATLAB/Simulink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56231825/how-do-you-connect-simscape-elements-to-other-elements-in-the-matlab-simulink)